# Error while loading the data through informatica mapping

Tags: unix, teradata, informatica

Can you please help me to find out solution for the below error message.

UTY4014 Access module error '34' received during 'set position' operation:
'pmUnxDskSetPos: fseek error (System error message detected: 29)'

Overview of the mapping:
My Source is Oracle and Teradata, I am joining both the tables in my mapping and loading it into the teradata table.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Which utility are you using?

Comment: If it's MLOAD, the release the MLOAD lock, drop the target table, error tables, log table etc and then rerun the job...

Comment: @visakh the target table only needs to be dropped if the failure occurred in the application phase.

Comment: Are you streaming this data via a named pipe to a Teradata utility via Informatica?

Comment: @visakh and Rob: Thank you so much for your replies. The problem resolved by dropping work tables and releasing mload. I re-ran the process.